# How to get rid of whitespace for grid.arrange function in RMD

Tags: r, whitespace, r-markdown, gridextra

So I'm generating 2 ggplots and then using Grid.arrange to plot them side by side in an rmd document. In order to do that, I have to set `ncol =2` as an argument in the grid.arrange function. The problem is when I do that, the graphs are very long.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
x1 = ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(mtcars$disp)) +
  geom_histogram()
x2 = ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(mtcars$mpg)) +
  geom_histogram()
# worse Graph without whitespace
grid.arrange(x1,x2, ncol =2)
```

So I tried to fix it by manually reducing the heights with the heights argument and setting `heights = c(2,2)` . But when I do this, there is an excessive amount of whitespace at the bottom.

```
grid.arrange(x1,x2, ncol =2, heights = c(2,2))
```

How do I get rid of this whitespace? I'm working in RMD and am creating output for a class report. This problem is reproducible both within the plots console in R and when the pdf output of the rmd file.

Comment: You can set the height of the figure in an R code chunk. For example `\```{r fig.height=4}`. Then run your plot code inside the chunk as usual. Adjust height to whatever value you wish. Also, you should use only bare column names inside `aes`, so remove `mtcars$` in the ggplot statements.

Comment: As eipi10 said, use r chunk option in RMD `fig.height` in whichever chunk your plot is.

Comment: @eipi10 thanks for the help! Only reason I did that was to use the tab autocomplete feature to help me find the exact column name. Is there anyway to allow tab autocomplete to work with the bare column names?

Comment: I don't think autocomplete works with bare column names inside ggplot2, though it would be nice if it did. However, you'll set yourself up for errors if you restate the data frame name inside `aes`.

Comment: Yes R base graphics requires data.frame$column_name.. ggplot requires input..and then later just column names directly no need to extract using $ symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fig.height` in r chunk

I. Without `fig.height`

````
```{r}
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
x1 = ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(mtcars$disp)) +
geom_histogram()
x2 = ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(mtcars$mpg)) +
geom_histogram()
# worse Graph without whitespace
grid.arrange(x1,x2, ncol =2)
```
````

II. With `fig.height`

````
```{r fig.height= 3}
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
x1 = ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(mtcars$disp)) +
geom_histogram()
x2 = ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(mtcars$mpg)) +
geom_histogram()
# worse Graph without whitespace
grid.arrange(x1,x2, ncol =2)
```
````

Output Difference in Knitted HTML

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!  I originally tried (unsuccesfully) playing with the fig.height and fig.width functions but only after I set `heights=c(2,2)`.  in the grid.arrange function. So I guess the grid.arrange function just doesn't play nice with whitespace and I should just set the plot size explicitly in the chunk

Comment: Hey it was first suggested by @eipi10 above in comments. I also knew it. Please ask him to oost answer as well if any other alternatives he could find. I was the 2nd one to suggest same thing.  Usimlng `fig.height` along with grid.arrange height..doesnt play along.. we have to think a bit abt it. Without heights..works!!

Comment: If you do not use rmd, then we have to think about some other options to provide vakues explicotly in heights, as you said you wanted it in rmd output..i.e. he best option you shud go for.. there are hell lots of r chunk options to customize your knitted output.

Comment: The `heights` argument is not really for creating white space (although you can use it for that purpose in a hacky sort of way). It's for determining the fraction of the total vertical space that is allotted to each row of plots in a multiplot layout. Since you only have two plots, `heights=c(2,2)` just creates a second (empty) row of plots that takes of half the total height of the plot layout (`heights=c(1,1)` would do the same; it's the ratio between the values that matters, not their absolute values).

Comment: (continued) You could, for example, do `heights=c(9,1)` and your two plots in the first row will get 90% of vertical space and the empty "row" below it will get 10% of the vertical space.

Comment: @eipi10 Thank you for providing information on heights.. in `grid.arrange()`